# Python JA3 Fingerprint Spoofing with sockets

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, urllib3

I would like to edit my own JA3 fingerprint in requests, I have modified my SSL, TLS, and Ciphers with UrlLib3 but there is no support for JA3 Fingerprints. How might I be able to spoof my JA3 Fingerprint within requests.

Comment: I don't think that Python gives you these level of access to the TLS stack, at least not with urlib3 or requests.